# How do I get my node app to perform 1000s of async operations at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

Once sitemap is entered by the user, here is the process I want my node app to perform.

1) all urls from sitemap are grabbed

2) each of the urls is visited and the meta data is extracted (using cheerio) - and saved to the db

3) each of the url's social count is fetched and saved to the db

4) each url is again visited and links are extracted from the url

5) each of the links that the urls gave out is visited and status code is checked and saved to the db

I've written controller actions for each of the above steps (using the async module) and individually they're working properly although when there's a big website, step #4 can go to 20k or 30k different urls and then step #5 actually visiting them results in quite a few 503 errors if the setTimeout is not fast enough so my question is, what's the best way to execute the above process?

was talking to a friend and he suggested that I look into Kue or RabbitMQ, but I've never worked with any such queue based modules so given what i'm trying to achieve, not quite sure what the best approach would be

feedback on the above would be fantastic

Comment: post your code. nodejs is perfect for this, you don't need a queue but maybe want to look into clustering.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I just realized you wanted a dynamic queue to be added to as you are in the queue already... sorry for the long response before. Take a look at [`async.queue()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), it might get you going in the right direction. Also look into possibly a Redis queue with child processes (redis-dist-job-queue, maybe?), possibly look at kju, though Kue does look like a good option as well. RabbitMQ looks like a full blown messaging service, which may be overkill for what you're looking for.